# Test method that returns void

Tags: java, testing, jdbc

I have a void method and I want to test it. How do I do that? 
Here's the method:

```
public void updateCustomerTagCount() {

    List<String> fileList = ImportTagJob.fetchData();
    try {
        for (String tag : fileList) {
            Long tagNo = Long.parseLong(tag);
            Customer customer = DatabaseInterface.getCustomer(tagNo);
            customer.incrementNoOfTimesRecycled();
            DatabaseInterface.UpdateCustomer(customer);  
        }
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Check the Customer before and after the method.

Comment: What do you want to test?

Comment: I have to update customer each time there's a new tagNo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when the method returns void, you can't test the method output. Instead, you must test what are the expected consequences of that method. For example:

```
public class Echo {
    String x;
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        testVoidMethod();
    }

    private static void testVoidMethod() {
        Echo e = new Echo();
        //x == null
        e.voidMethod("xyz");
        System.out.println("xyz".equals(e.x)); //true expected
    }

    private void voidMethod(String s) {
        x = s;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be always true, but basic concept of unit test is to check if function works as expected and properly handling errors when unexpected parameters/situation is given.
So basically unit test is against the functions that takes input parameters and return some output so we can write those unit test.

The code like yours, however, includes some other dependency (database call) and that's something you can't execute unless you write integration-test code or real database connection related one and actually that's not recommended for unit test.

So what you need to do might be introducing unit test framework, especially Mockto/Powermock or some other stuff that provides object mocking feature. With those test framework, you can simulate database operation or other function call that is going to be happening outside of your test unit code.

Also, about *how do I test void function*, there is nothing you can with Assert feature to compare output since it returns nothing as you mentioned.
But still, there is a way for unit test.

1. Just call updateCustomerTagCount() to make sure function works. Even with just calling the function, those unit test can raise your unit test coverage.
   Of course for your case, you need to mock

ImportTagJob.fetchData();

and

DatabaseInterface.getCustomer(tagNo);

and have to.

1. Let mocked

ImportTagJob.fetchData();

throw empty list as well as non-empty list  and check if your code works as you expected. Add exception handling if necessary. In your code, there are two condition depends on whether fieList are null or non-null, you need to test it.

Also, mock those objects and let them throw IllegalArgumentException where you expect it to be thrown, and write an unit test if the function throws a exception. In Junit, it should be like

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void updateCustomerTagCountTest(){
    // mock the objects 
    xxxxx.updateCustomerTagCount();
}
```

That way, you can ensure that function will throw exception properly when it has to.